# Greying out the Cell

Tags: excel, vba

`ThisWorksheet.range("C24").Select` did not work

---

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4).Activate`

`Range("C24").Select`

Did not work

---

Any suggestions guys? Thanks

Comment: Your question is missing some important information. **In what way** did those attempts not work?  You got an error message? The wrong range was selected?

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C24").Select`

Alternatively, you can use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C24").Select`

Comment: @user2569803, if this has corrected your problem, please select as answer (the tick below the down arrow) - otherwise this question will remain "unanswered" to the rest of the users :)